# ansible cisco modifying multiple object-groups with single playbook lines

Tags: ansible, cisco

I have following playbook to modify ASA object-group:

```
    ---
- hosts: us_asa   
  connection: local   
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:
    - name: change config
      asa_config:
        auth_pass: "{{ ansible_ssh_password }}"
        username: "{{ ansible_ssh_user }}"
        password: "{{ ansible_ssh_password }}"
        authorize: yes
        timeout: 45
        lines:
          - network-object host 1.2.3.4
          - network-object host 2.3.2.3
        parents: ['object-group network BAD_IPs']
```

This works fine for single group.

Any suggestion how to modify multiple groups with same connection?  If I add another object-group after `parents: ['object-group network BAD_IPs']` example:

```
    ---
- hosts: us_asa   
  connection: local   
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:
    - name: change config
      asa_config:
        auth_pass: "{{ ansible_ssh_password }}"
        username: "{{ ansible_ssh_user }}"
        password: "{{ ansible_ssh_password }}"
        authorize: yes
        timeout: 45
        lines:
          - network-object host 1.2.3.4
          - network-object host 2.3.2.3
        parents: ['object-group network BAD_IPs']
          - network-object host 4.4.4.4
        parents: ['object-group network Good_IPs']
```

This fails 
The offending line appears to be:

```
    parents: ['object-group network BAD_IPs']
      - network-object host 4.4.4.4
      ^ here
```

Any recommendation on syntax I should use?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have a basic YAML syntax error there.  A YAML dictionary key with a list value looks either like this:

```
key: [item1, item2, item3]
```

Or like this:

```
key:
  - item1
  - item2
  - item3
```

You have some weird combination of the two:

```
    parents: ['object-group network BAD_IPs']
      - network-object host 4.4.4.4
```

I don't know exactly what structure you want, but what you have there is simply invalid.

Comment: I based off of this, and seems to work for single object-group but not if i want to modify multiple groups.http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/asa_config_module.html

Comment: Take a close look at the syntax in those examples.  Now take a close look at this answer.  You'll note that they are both telling you the same thing: you need to pick one list syntax or the other and then stick with it.  You're trying to use both.

Comment: ...although I will note, syntax aside, I'm not familiar with the cisco modules and I don't know if you can do what you want to do once you've fixed your syntax issues.